# MYSQL IN substitute

Tags: mysql

Good day

I am trying to query the names of employees who work on every project.
My code is as follows:

```
SELECT CONCAT (fname,' ', minit,'. ' , lname) AS NAME
FROM employee a, works_on b, project c
WHERE pno IN (Select pnumber      //WHAT COULD I SUBSTITUTE W/ IN
              FROM projet) 
     AND a.ssn = b.essn
     AND b.pno = c.pnumber
```

The problem with IN is that it is that the values inside are like evaluated as 'OR'...  what is the equivalent of IN that makes the value of my subquery evaluated like 'AND'

Thank you in advance.

EDIT: 
As reqeusted..

[image]

Comment: I don't understand. How can a column have multiple values at the same time?

Comment: What @Pekka means is, `WHERE a IN ('b', 'c')` is equivalent to `WHERE a = 'b' OR a = 'c'`. What you want is `WHERE a = 'b' AND a = 'c'` but how can `a` be both `'b'` and `'c'` at the same time?

Comment: .. it *is* clear  what you want though, this is just not the way to do it. I'm not sure *how* to do this - anyway, you will need to show your table structures and the relations

Comment: So what can I do? I tried WHERE pno = ALL(Select pnumber FROM project) it's also wrong

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    employee e
WHERE   NOT EXISTS
        (
        SELECT  NULL
        FROM    employee ei
        CROSS JOIN
                project p
        LEFT JOIN
                works_on wo
        ON      wo.pno = p.pnumber
                AND wo.essn = ei.ssn
        WHERE   ei.ssn = e.ssn
        )
```

Comment: I bow to your SQL mastery. Nice!

Answer (score 2):

```
select CONCAT (fname,' ', minit,'. ' , lname) AS NAME 
from employee 
left join works_on 
on works_on.essn=employee.ssn 
group by employee.ssn 
having count(works_on.essn) =  (select count(*) from project);
```

Answer (score 1):

Simplified example:

```
create table emp_work_on
(
emp_name varchar(50),
work_on varchar(30)
);


create table works
(
work_on varchar(30)
);

insert into works(work_on) values('apple'),('microsoft'),('google'),('facebook')



insert into emp_work_on values
('john','apple'),('john','microsoft'),('john','google'),('john','facebook'),
('paul','microsoft'),('paul','google'),
('george','apple'),('george','microsoft'),('george','google'),('george','facebook'),
('ringo','apple'),('ringo','facebook');


select e.emp_name
from works w
left join emp_work_on e on e.work_on = w.work_on
group by e.emp_name
having count(e.work_on) = (select count(*) from works)
order by e.emp_name
```

Output:

```
emp_name 
----------
 george
 john
(2 rows)
```

On your table structure, you could use this:

```
SELECT * FROM employee 
WHERE ssn IN
(
    SELECT w.essn
    FROM project c
    LEFT JOIN works_on w ON w.pno = c.pnumber
    GROUP BY w.essn
    HAVING COUNT(w.pno) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM project)
)
```

Hmm.. but I think this could be the simplest, granting there's no repeating pno on employee's works_on, i.e. there's no pno in works_on that doesn't exists on project, i.e. referential integrity is maintained

```
SELECT * FROM employee 
WHERE ssn IN
(
    SELECT essn
    FROM works_on
    GROUP BY essn
    HAVING COUNT(pno) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM project)
)
```